# Compact PST files using Redemption

Tags: outlook-redemption

Is it possible to shrink, compress, or compact a PST store using Redemption? I can't seem to find anything on the subject so I assume no.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to do that progmatically through C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no programmatic access to that feature exposed by the PST provider.

Comment: It appears though that doing a Items.MoveMultiple to a different PST, then saving the original one will compact it automatically. Well, at least if you did a LogonPstStore initially. That's good enough for my needs. I assume the same would happen if you permadeleted something out of the original PST as well.